# How to get the element in the control template in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I want to get the element in the control template from code behind.

In the XAML below I want to get the **Border element "btnBorder"** and change the color from red to any other color from **code behind**.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel    
           Name ="st"
                Margin="0,3,0,3"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="btn" Height="22" Margin="0,0,25,0">
                <Button.Template x:Uid="dd">
                    <ControlTemplate x:Name="tmp" TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="btnBorder" Background="Red">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />                            
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>

                Test Button
            </Button>

        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have tried various methods like

GetTemplateChild("btnBorder")
object o = template.FindName("btnBorder", this.btn);

but these methods are returning null.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong or what is the correct way to access the template child from code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `BorderBrush` of your `Button` and bind it with `BorderBrush` of `Border` control in ControlTemplate.

So when you will set `BorderBrush` for your `Button` from code behind it will reflect to underlying binding and so on your `Border` control in `ControlTemplate`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="btnBorder"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>                            
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

This is how you can apply the `Style`

```
<StackPanel>

<Button Style={StaticResource MyButtonStyle} Name="btn1" Content="Test Button 1" 
        BorderBrush="Red"/>

<Button Style={StaticResource MyButtonStyle} Name="btn2" Content="Test Button 2" 
        BorderBrush="Green"/>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nitesh but I have 7-8 instance of this button then how can I differentiate between these instances.. I mean I need to have different colors for different button.

Comment: So create a style and apply it to your buttons.